# GAE - Setting VM to true and shared libraries altogether

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtual-machine

I've been trying to use MySql when VM true flag is setted to true on my app.yaml

but this error is thrown: appcfg.py: error: Error parsing src/app.yaml: The "libraries:" directive has been deprecated for Managed VMs. Please delete this section from your app.yaml, use pip (https://pip.pypa.io/) to install
 your dependencies, and save them to a requirements.txt.  For more information, please visit http://cloud.google.com/python.

I didn't find anything specific for this error, where should I put this "requirement.txt", anyone had this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with flexible environments (previously called Managed Virtual Machines) then you can't use the "libraries" directive in your app.yaml in order to activate third party libraries. Instead of that you should use pip to install your dependencies. From [oficial docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#hello_world_code_review);

> Requirements.txt and the Python package manager pip are used to
>   declare and install application dependencies.

The documentation also is explicit when the author write;

> Requirements.txt defines the libraries that will be installed both locally and when
>   deploying to App Engine.

You should put the requirement.txt file in the root directory. [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/hello_world_compat) you can see a example where flask library was imported.

In your development environment you can run the following command in order to install your declared libraries.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Pip is default way to install libraries in python envs. [Here](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/) you can find a very nice documentation.

**Update:**

You should use the following command to deploy:

```
gcloud proview app deploy
```

Take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app#deploying) for more details.

Also, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/cloudsql) there is a official example of your use case. I can see a little difference, the author is using PyMySQL==0.7.3 instead of MySQL-python.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually helped me. I put "MySQL-python=1.2.5" on requirements.txt but when I upload it the error "No module named MySQL" is thrown at me. Do you know if I have to "force" the installation once I uploaded to gae? Btw I'm using appcfg.py -A <appname> update app.yaml, should I use gcloud preview app deploy instead?

Comment: My question related to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625838/gae-python-no-module-named-mysqldb

Comment: Hi Dyego, yes you should use gcloud proview app deploy command. Take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app#deploying). Anyway, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/cloudsql) there is a official example of your use case. I can see a little difference, the author is using PyMySQL==0.7.3 instead of MySQL-python.

Comment: Hi @Dyego! Please mark your question as aswered for me. 

Comment: I'd love to, just put your comment as an answer and I'll do it.

Comment: @Dyego, done. I've updated my answer on top. Also in the related question. Regards.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for being late to accept your answer ;)