# GAE Python - No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

Recently I switched to "vm: true" on my app.yaml. Since then I'm having some issues regarding the MySQLdb library.

I'm trying to import MySQL  like this:

```
import MySQLdb
```

My requirements.txt looks like this:

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

I figured that I wasn't supposed to use "libraries" inside my app.yaml and should put all my  dependencies on the "requirements.txt".

I uploaded several times with/without this file but this error is thrown:

```
No module named MySQLdb
```

It works fine locally.

Anyone had this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Dyego, Are u using "gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml" command to deploy?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nico I'll try that soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following command to deploy:

```
gcloud preview app deploy
```

Take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app#deploying) for more details.

Also, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/cloudsql) there is a official example of your use case. I can see a little difference, the author is using PyMySQL==0.7.3 instead of MySQL-python.